# Как выделить область в режиме редактирования, на террейне?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть террейн, на нём надо выделить область, в которой будут взрывы. Допустим у нас область круг, овал, квадрат, прямоугольник или ромб. Как подсветить, любым цветом, область которую мы зададим?